# Show that the Laurent Polynomials form a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I am asked to show that the set of Laurent Polynomials with coefficients is a field k forms a ring with an identity. 
The Laurent Polynomial ring is denoted $K[x,x^{-1}]$:

So for a ring I need to show:

$K[x,x^{-1}]$ is an abelian group under addition

Multiplication in $K[x,x^{-1}]$: is associative

Mulitplication in $K[x,x^{-1}]$: distributes over addition

So, to show $K[x,x^{-1}]$: is an abelian group under addition, it suffices to show:

for p=$\sum p_{f}X^{f}$ where $f_i \in K$,

To show it is abelian under addition:

$\sum a_{i}X^{i}$+$\sum b_{i} X^{i}$ = $\sum b_{i}X^{i}$+$\sum a_{i} X^{i}$

Does it suffice to say: $\sum a_{i}X^{i}$+$\sum b_{i} X^{i}$=$\sum (a_{i}+b_{i})X^{i}$=$\sum (b_{i}+a_{i})X^{i}$= $\sum b_{i}X^{i}$+$\sum a_{i} X^{i}$ ?

For multiplication is associative:

$\left ( \sum a_iX^i \right )(\left ( \sum b_jX^j\right )\left ( \sum c_hX^h\right ))=\sum_{f}\left ( \sum _{(i,j,hi+j+h=f)} a_i(b_jc_h)\right )X^f=\sum_{f}\left ( \sum _{(i,j,i+j=f)} (a_ib_j)c_h\right )X^f=((\left ( \sum a_iX^i \right )\left ( \sum b_jX^j\right ))\left ( \sum c_hX^h\right )$

Is this ok so far?

Comment: Associativity of multiplication is $a(bc) = (ab)c$ rather than what you are trying to show ($ab = ba$) which is commutativity.

Comment: It seems you are dealing with Laurent "series" having only a finite number of terms?

Comment: stupid mistake. I will edit the second part, does the first part look right?

Comment: Second part it edited, and yes, I assumed finite polynomials, but the same arguement would work for infinite polynomials right? I would just need to change the summation notation?

Comment: You mean the part where you show commutativity of addition? Yes, if somewhat lacking in rigor...for instance, it would have been nice to mention that without loss of generality you may assume that $\Sigma a_i X^i$ and $\Sigma b_i X^i$ have the same number of (finite) terms since if the first one had fewer terms, you can just add a bunch of $0 \cdot X^j$'s afterward to equal them out.

Comment: Also, there is a much slicker way of showing that $\mathbf{F}[X, X^{-1}]$ is a ring: note that the polynomials in two indeterminates over field $\mathbf{F}$ is a ring: $\mathbf{F}[X, Y]$. Taking the quotient by the ideal $(XY - 1)$ also gives you a ring: $\mathbf{F}[X, Y]/(XY - 1)$. But the latter is "just" $\mathbf{F}[X, X^{-1}]$.

Comment: Hmm, ok. I just learned about rings yesterday so this doesn't quite make sense yet. Im not familiar with the phrase "polynomials in two indeterminates over field F is a ring: F[X,Y]" Also, we haven't discussed ideals yet...